# Excel VBA Dynamic data validation drop downs with multiple criteria ranking

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I am trying to create a dynamic drop down data validation list that will rank multiple criteria (#2 or more) from a worksheet, there are 300 items in my list and I want to rank them based on information in another worksheet in a table.

Based on the rank (1 to 300) I would like the drop down data validation list to contain top 10, top 25 and top/bottom # values calculated from their rank. I don't mind helper columns. If the data/table I am ranking from changes, and/or if I want to add a criteria I would like the top 10, top 25 etc to change accordingly.

I have recorded with the macro recorder when I use the advanced filter and also the top 25 in this case values.

```
Sub Makro2()
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("T[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Range("A1:J3"), Unique:=False

Range("T[[#Headers],[2017]]").Select
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

Selection.AutoFilter

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("T").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="25", _
    Operator:=xlTop10Items
End Sub
```

Is this possible in Excel 2016 with or without VBA?

Edit: I found this thread [Data Validation drop down list not auto-updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332607/data-validation-drop-down-list-not-auto-updating) and this code in that thread could be what I am looking for.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' Ensure all lists are made from tables and that these tables are named
' in the Name Manager.
' When creating your Data Validation List, instead of selecting a range
' in 'Source', click within 'Source' and press 'F3'. Finally select your
' tables name.
Dim strValidationList As String
Dim strVal As String
Dim lngNum As Long

On Error GoTo Nevermind
strValidationList = Mid(Target.Validation.Formula1, 2)
strVal = Target.Value
lngNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(strVal, ThisWorkbook.Names(strValidationList).RefersToRange, 0)

' Converts table contents into a formula
If strVal <> "" And lngNum > 0 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Formula = "=INDEX(" & strValidationList & ", " & lngNum & ")"
End If

Nevermind:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Update:

I am using the LARGE function to get the top 15 values of Table1. I am then using INDEX and MATCH to find the names of the top 15 values (column 2).

I am then using the OFFSET function and a NAMED RANGE to get a data validation list that auto updates when I add something to the bottom of the list.

Now I want the data validation list to be dependent on the first drop down. How can I achieve this?

Comment: At the moment I am using Excel's advanced filter to filter on two criteria, sort by size and then rank using RANK

Comment: AutoFilter already allows filtering by a "Top" # or %. Here's a [tutorial](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/quick-start-filter-data-by-using-an-autofilter-08647e19-11d1-42f6-b376-27b932e186e0).

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial. How can I use the top # or % in a dynamic (not manually updated) data validation list?

Comment: @wairmea  I find that the easiest way to automate something like this (and to learn in the process) is to get it working manually, record your actions, and adapt the recorded code as necessary.   I'm not sure what you are wanting to change dynamically (as the question didn't include detail or examples or sample data)

Comment: If you're already familiar with Excel, see: [**Recording a Macro to Generate Code**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code) as well as [**Revising Recorded Visual Basic Macros**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros). If you're not familiar with Excel (or whatever you're planning on automating with VBA), do that before attempting VBA.  This VBA tutorial's also pretty good: [**Excel VBA For Beginners**](//www.homeandlearn.org/) and [Microsoft's Documentation](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/vba-language-reference).

Comment: I have recorded the advanced filter but it doesn't show the criteria it only names them as criteria. What I want to update and change dynamically is the list range from where my data validation table is set from, based on the rank of the items before they go into the list.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `doesn't show the criteria it only names them as criteria` - please [edit] your question to add the section of code you're referring to, as well as example data or background.  (Pretend you're explaining this to someone who's never seen your data before.)  ...also some important tips: [ask] and how to create a **[mcve]** plus [these tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching it correctly, sorting or filtering your list data prior to loading the list.  I am confused about your question but it appears you are wondering how to create the data validation drop down after you have manipulated your list?

Here is an example of how this is done with a simple test code written to build a state list and then a county list based on the state chosen.  Maybe this helps you build your validation lists.

There are two worksheets:

1) one for Data List items ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataList")

2) one for the drop downs ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DD Report Testing")

In a module Create_State_List

```
Option Explicit

'This is a two part validation, select a state and then select a county

Sub CreateStateList()
   Dim FirstDataRow As Double, LastDataRow As Double
   Dim StateCol As Double, CountyCol As Double
   Dim DataListSht As Worksheet
   Dim DDReportSht As Worksheet

   Dim StateListLoc As String
   Dim StateRange As Range

   Set DataListSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataList")
   Set DDReportSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DD Report Testing")
   FirstDataRow = 3 'First row with a State
   StateCol = 2 'States are in Col 2 ("B")
   LastDataRow = DataListSht.Cells(DataListSht.Rows.Count, StateCol).End(xlUp).Row

   Set StateRange = DataListSht.Range(DataListSht.Cells(FirstDataRow, StateCol), DataListSht.Cells(LastDataRow, StateCol))

   StateListLoc = "D3" 'This is where the drop down is located / will be updated

   DDReportSht.Range(StateListLoc).ClearContents 'Clear the list as we build dynamically
   DDReportSht.Range(StateListLoc).Validation.Delete 'Clear the Validation

   'Create the State List
   With Range(StateListLoc).Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=DataList!" & StateRange.Address
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Sub
```

In a module Create_County_List

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CreateCountyList(StateChosen As String)

    Dim DataListSht As Worksheet
    Dim DDReportSht As Worksheet
    Dim StateRow As Double
    Dim NumStateCols As Double
    Dim StartStateCol As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastDataRow As Double
    Dim CountyRange As Range
    Dim CountyListLoc As String

    Set DataListSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataList")
    Set DDReportSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DD Report Testing")
    NumStateCols = 51 'We count the District of Columbia
    StateRow = DataListSht.Range("C2").Row
    StartStateCol = DataListSht.Range("C2").Column

    For i = 0 To NumStateCols 'Account for starting at zero rather than 1

        If CStr(Trim(DataListSht.Cells(StateRow, StartStateCol + i))) = StateChosen Then
            'find the last Data row in the column where the match is
            LastDataRow = DataListSht.Cells(DataListSht.Rows.Count, StartStateCol + i).End(xlUp).Row

            'Make the Dynamic list of Counties based on the state chosen
            Set CountyRange = DataListSht.Range(DataListSht.Cells(StateRow + 1, StartStateCol + i), DataListSht.Cells(LastDataRow, StartStateCol + i))

            CountyListLoc = "D4"

            DDReportSht.Range(CountyListLoc).ClearContents
            DDReportSht.Range(CountyListLoc).Validation.Delete

            'Create the County List
            With Range(CountyListLoc).Validation
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=DataList!" & CountyRange.Address
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With

           'Break loop
           i = 1000 ' should break loop off right here
        Else 'do not build a list
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

The Worksheet contains the Cell selection code

```
Option Explicit

'This routine will react to changes to a cell in the worksheet
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim DDReportSht As Worksheet
    Dim StateString As String
    Set DDReportSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DD Report Testing")

    Call CheckStatusBar 'Lets update the Status bar on selection changes

    'If the cell change is D3 on DD report (they want state so build list for state)
    If Not Intersect(Target, DDReportSht.Range("D3")) Is Nothing Then
            'Clear the county list until the state is chosen to avoid mismatch
            DDReportSht.Range("D4").ClearContents
            DDReportSht.Range("D4").Validation.Delete

            '*** Create the State Drop Down
            Call CreateStateList

    Else 'Do nothing
    End If


    'If the cell change is D4 on DD report (they want the county list so build it based on the state in D3)
    If Not Intersect(Target, DDReportSht.Range("D4")) Is Nothing Then
        'If there was a change to the state list go get the county list set up
        StateString = DDReportSht.Range("D3")
        Application.Run "Create_County_List.CreateCountyList", StateString
    Else 'Do nothing
    End If

    'If cell is D7 build a rig list
    If Not Intersect(Target, DDReportSht.Range("D7")) Is Nothing Then
        'Build the Rig List
        Call CreateRigList
    Else 'Do nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

DataSet:
[image]

Test Validation Worksheet in practice, again it is just a demo:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I am just beginning to learn VBA but I have your code running, however I only get one data validation drop down(in cell #D3) ?The code does update the range dynamically which is great. You have commented the code but if you want to could you please tell me why the code is in 3 different modules?

Comment: The next drop down is in D4 (county) dependent on D3 (state) being previously filled out.  The Subs could all be in the worksheet code, but as you expand your projects you will find that you will want to encapsulate your code functions were you can get to them quickly, if you wanted to replace to modify, export, or import the module into another project this is the easy way.  It is especially important to "untangle your code dependencies" as VBA teases you into making one huge mega sub, FYI - there is a limit to how many lines of code or # of subs you can have in a given module.

Comment: This shows how to "load" your validation lists.  If you can explain what your data looks like and how you want to sort it, we can provide examples of filter and/or sort prior to loading the "lists".  Sometimes you use this method, excel based form, sometimes you might want to pop up a form with a listbox of items for the users to select from. Another method.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for your code. I have setup my data according to your picture, I am also using states and county's but CountyListLoc never gets called? I tried to add a debug.print to a couple of places but nothing gets printed to the immediate window. I get a dynamic drop down in cell D3 in DD Report Testing but still no D4?

Comment: I think that your code is exactly what I want and what I need for my project. I select a state in D3 and then the county's for that state gets loaded into D4? Could you upload a picture on the two dropdowns.

Comment: are you selecting D4 after making your selection in D3? . . . Edited with photo

Comment: Are you sure the test code works? I think that I am missing something, I can get drop down boxes in D3 and D4 (sometimes?) but D4 contains the same values as D3. When I update D3 nothing happens to D4.

Comment: Positive that it works for the data set, the data you are using is not in the the same format then (row, column) All of the states and all of the counties are present in the data set, they run from Alabama in C2 to Wyoming in BB2), this is just to demo what is possible to others, in practice I actually update the list items from a database (change the lists for many users in one place) and then load forms w/lists.  You probably do not have the entire data set or rows and columns. D4 will clear if there is no state chosen (D3).  If you select D3 and D4 but go back to D3 it clears both.

Comment: just make your data set a dummy set, whatever you put in column A as a lookup, be sure you have a search column with items beside it.  you can have two items, itemA and itemB in your master column, then beside it header itemA and then itemB, put a list of stuff underneath those two.  I would share the whole demo with you but there is not a way to include it.

Comment: Are there any parts of the code that you could change quickly to adapt it to my datalist? And remove the parts where D4 clears if there is no state chosen and if I select D3 and D4 where it clears both?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what your data field looks like, but now that you have a feeling for data validation lists, you can post about a multi criteria  = multi line sort, I have some examples of those once you choose your data range and key fields, but better in another question.  That would stick with your code approach, adjust the list before you load it based on sort conditions chosen.

Comment: I asked a new question on multi line sorting in Excel 2016 and I am curious about your examples! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215542/multi-line-sort-by-multiple-criteria-in-excel-2016

Comment: Would it be possible to use this code with combo boxes?

Comment: Could anyone test the code above and see if it works for you? I can't get it to work.

Comment: I have tested it, it is working, but it is built around a data set and data set location.  Those are the only two concerns you should have in getting it to work for you.  I can post the entire code for you but it still will not work if the data is not set up in columns as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: you want to change code to xlDescending, but same idea applies

> Prior to worksheet_change event firing, we see that range is unsorted. The first ten items showing as options in the cell D1 are the first ten items in the range.

[image]

> When we make a change to a value in range I1:I20 we trigger the worksheet_change event. Inside this function we have code that will sort the range H1:I20.

[image]

> Here is the code for the worksheet_change function, and where it is to be placed that is inside the worksheet module of the worksheet that you are working with

[image]

> Finally here is how to link your data validation restrictions with the range. Changes to the range H1:I10 (aka the top ten) will change the options available to you in the box.

[image]

> The snippet of code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim rangeOfTable As Range
            Set rangeOfTable = ActiveSheet.Range("H1:I20")

        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rangeOfTable) Is Nothing Then
            rangeOfTable.Sort Range("I1:I20"), xlAscending
        End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: Works with dropDown boxes too

[image]

[image]

EDIT: this code will give you idea RE how to sort multiple values

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim rangeOfTable As Range
            Set rangeOfTable = ActiveSheet.Range("H1:J20")

        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rangeOfTable) Is Nothing Then
            With rangeOfTable
                .Sort key1:=ActiveSheet.Range("I1:I20"), order1:=xlAscending, _
                    key2:=ActiveSheet.Range("J1:J20"), Order2:=xlAscending
            End With
        End If
End Sub
```

> here is the data after the event has triggered, notice that the top ten in the list are the only ten available in the drop down box

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it is very clever!

Comment: thank you! works with combo boxes too (going with hard sell : - p )

Comment: Does it work with dependable drop downs and/or dependable combo boxes?

Comment: added multi sort