# Excel VBA Multi line sort by multiple criteria in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

Continued from this thread: [Dynamic data valdiation drop downs with multiple critera ranking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51198558/dynamic-data-valdiation-drop-downs-with-multiple-critera-ranking/51200469?noredirect=1#comment89411736_51200469)

I want to sort a list based on multiple criteria and then rank it and finally display it in a drop down data validation list (drop downs are covered in the thread referenced in the link above).

How can I sort data on multiple critera in Excel 2016? I have tried using the advanced filter and the worksheetChange event. I want to manipulate the data before I sort it and I want to rank the data before I sort it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$D$2" Then
    Range("ÄB1[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
                       CriteriaRange:=Range("D1:D2"), Unique:=False
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confusing that you are selecting a cell that is included in the sort.

This will filter a range of data (A1:D15) based on Column A as the key (sorts on A).
A range sorted on a single key if you will.

```
Sub sortbyColumnA()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Name your worksheet right here

    If ws.AutoFilterMode = False Then ws.Range("A1:D15").AutoFilter
    ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ws.AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ws.Range("A1:D15").AutoFilter
End Sub
```

[image]

Here is an example of a multi key sort of course you will need multiples in the first sort for the second sort key to be effective, and the same for multiples in the second sort for the third sort key.  You can sort on as many keys as you wish, depends on how big the data set is.
Its sorts first by Rank - second by first name - third by points (ascending maybe you want descending here - hint hint)

```
Sub sortbyMultiColumn()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Name your worksheet right here

        If ws.AutoFilterMode = False Then ws.Range("A1:D33").AutoFilter
        ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        'First Sort
        ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        'Second Sort
        ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        'Third Sort
        ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        With ws.AutoFilter.Sort
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

        ws.Range("A1:D33").AutoFilter

    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much!